# get a Telerik Radgrid column value?

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to do a foreach loop through every Radgrid row. If the column value is an 'N' I change the image icon, if it is a 'P' I change the ImageURL to point to another Icon.

Unfortunately I have tried a few things but I cannot get the `strTranslationValue` Column value.

How is it done?

```
List<AppFile> fileList = GetFileList();
grdFiles.DataSource = fileList != null ? fileList : (object)string.Empty;
grdFiles.PageSize = fileList.Count;
grdFiles.DataBind();

foreach (GridDataItem item in grdFiles.Items)
{
      string strTranslationValue = item.GetDataKeyValue("sComment").ToString();
      Image iconComment = (Image)item.FindControl("translationImg");
      iconComment.ImageUrl = "~/images/approved_icon.png";
}
```

Update:
Trying to use ItemDataBound event..

```
protected void grdFiles_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.DataItem  is AppFile) {
        GridItem gItem = (GridItem)e.Item;
        string strTranslationValue = gItem["sComments"].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to subscribe to the ItemDataBound event of the grid and then try to find the control using e.Item.FindControl(..)

But first you need to check whether e.Item.DataItem is AppFile, because the event fires for things like grid header, grid footer, etc.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev ty, trying this.. adding example code to question. What is the best way to get the column value.. I "THOUGHT" it was sComment..

Comment: @VeselinVasilev I got it.. `string strTranslationValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "sComment").ToString();`